# Android volley how to receive and send a json

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I making an app and in a specific part I send a string and receive a json. I USE VOLLEY
It works good, but now i need to send a json.

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
 public static final String DATA_URL = "http://unynote.esy.es/cas/read_allorder.php?id=";  // THIS HAVE TO CHANGE JUST TO LOCALHOST:8080/LOGIN
```

HERE:

```
public class Config {
public static final String DATA_URL = "http://unynote.esy.es/cas/read_allorder.php?id=";  // THIS HAVE TO CHANGE JUST TO LOCALHOST:8080/LOGIN
public static final String KEY_NAME = "COD_ALUMNO";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "COD_ASIGNATURA";
public static final String KEY_VC = "GRUPO_SECCION";

public static final String KEY_AULA = "AULA";
public static final String KEY_DIA = "DIA";
public static final String KEY_INICIO = "INICIO";
public static final String KEY_FIN = "FIN";

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";

 }
```

AND HERE IS THE PART OF VOLLEY CODE

```
public class TabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
 View.OnClickListener {

private EditText editTextId;
private Button buttonGet;
private TextView textViewResult;

private ProgressDialog loading;

int cont=1;
String[ ] contenido = new String[7];
String f="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainint);

    editTextId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
    buttonGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
    textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

    buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void getData() {
    String id = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
    if (id.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter an id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

    String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "si", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            showJSON(response);
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(TabsActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String response){

   // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String name="";
    String address="";
    String grupo = "";
    String aula = "";
    String dia = "";
    String inicio = "";
    String fin = "";



    try {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "LOGIN... ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

        JSONArray ja = jsonObject.getJSONArray("orders");
        // JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject collegeData = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            name = collegeData.getString("id");
            address = collegeData.getString("item");
             grupo = collegeData.getString("GRUPO_SECCION");
             aula = collegeData.getString("AULA");
             dia = collegeData.getString("DIA");
             inicio = collegeData.getString("INICIO");
             fin = collegeData.getString("FIN");

            ///database
            DBAdapter db= new DBAdapter(this);

            db.open();
            long id = db.insertContact(address, aula,dia,inicio,fin );
            db.close();

            db.open();
            Cursor c = db.getAllContacts();
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            { do{
                contenido=getcontenido(c);

            }while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
            cont= Integer.parseInt( contenido[0]);
            /// database

            /// alarms
            int [] time;
            time = parsetime(inicio);

            int horai = time[0];
            int minutoi = time[1];
            int diaa = getDay(dia);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, horai);
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutoi);
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, diaa);
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 2);


            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", address);
            //intent.putExtra("curos bn",1);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
                            cont+1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );




            AlarmManager alarmManager =
                    (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000 , pendingIntent);


            ////alarms



            f=f+"codigo alumno:\t"+name+"\ncodigo/nombre curso:\t" +address+ "\ngrupo:\t"+grupo+"\naula:\t"
            +aula+"\ndia:\t"+dia+"\ninicio:\t"+inicio+"\nfin:\t"+fin+"\n:\t";

        }
        //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  collegeData.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //collegeData.toString();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    textViewResult.setText(f);
}
```

I JUS SENT THE STRING editTextId.getText() . That is a code for each user , but now i need to send a json with that string .

'CCODUSU'  '45875621'

CCODUSU is the identifier

Comment: Before you start using that library, please switch to Retrofit:https://github.com/square/retrofit.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at StringRequests. Here is an example of how to send things to a PHP file, which updates a database, or can do whatever:

**SetMyStuff.java:**

```
package com.example.your_app.database_requests;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SetMyStuff extends StringRequest {

    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://example.com/SetMyStuff.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public SetMyStuff(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

}
```

To call this StringRequest:

```
Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                        if (!success) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Could not update stuff.");
                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Updated stuff.");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            SetMyStuff setMyStuffRequest = new SetMyStuff(username, password, listener);
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            requestQueue.add(setMyStuffRequest);
```

The PHP file that recieves this:

```
<?php

    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $con = mysqli_connect("website.com", "dbusername", "dbpassword", "dbtable");

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;

    /* Do something */
    $response["success"] = true;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: Personally, I'd give the Hashmap as a parameter on its own rather than the strings, and later putting them in the map anyways

Comment: im doing the web service in python and its ok . but what is totalLocationsRequest ????

Comment: As I stated, this was copied from one of my apps. I fixed the totalLocationsRequest... I forgot to change that. The json is getting sent when it says `echo json_encode ($response)`. That json is getting accepted in the app in the listener portion of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you need send a `JSON` which contains the `editTextId.getText().toString().trim()`, if you want to do this, you must spell out a complete and correct `JSON`.

```
'CCODUSU' '45875621'
```

The string you post is not a `json`, you need to modify it into this:

```
{"CCODUSU": "45875621"}
```

Once you give this string after your `Config.DATA_URL`, the server will receive the `id` parameter and it is the `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

I also came up with this same issue.On the course of finding way I have developed a way that might help you.
If you want to post json to the server then you can create JsonObjectRequest as:

```
public class AppJSONObjectRequest extends JsonObjectRequest{

private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
private Map<String, String> headers;

public AppJSONObjectRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonObject, Response.Listener<JSONObject> reponseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, Map<String, String> headers) {
    super(method, url, jsonObject, reponseListener, errorListener);
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = reponseListener;
}

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JSONException je) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
    }
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers;
}
}
```

And then you can use this jave file in your activity or fragment to send json and recieve response like this below:

```
JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
    try {

        parameters.put("f_name", "name1");
        parameters.put("l_name", "name2");
        .......


    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    AppJSONObjectRequest objectRequest = new AppJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, url, parameters, RequestSuccessListener, RequestErrorListener, getHeaders); //headers if u have
    //url: your request base url

    VolleySingleton volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this);
    volleySingleton.addToRequestQueue(objectRequest);
```

And you can receive json as :

```
Response.Listener<JSONObject> RequestSuccessListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        Log.i(TAG, "Response" + " " + response);

    }
};

Response.ErrorListener RequestErrorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        error.printStackTrace();

    }
};
```

you can get headers as:

```
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {

    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("x-auth-token", Constant.API_KEY_X_AUTH_TOKEN);
    return headers;
}
```

VolleySingleton class

```
public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton mInstance;
private Context mContext;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;


private VolleySingleton(Context context){
    this.mContext = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue() ;
}

public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
        // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req){
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
}
```

Just you can implement above sample... then hope you will get what you want.it may be copy paste code but it covers overall enough to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the value in dealing with Headers here

Comment: I have updated my code... with addition of header value

Comment: Right, I'm just saying the question isn't really asking for header values. It's nice to have, just not necessary to get the question answered

Comment: ya with the question asked it is not neccessary to mention about the header value but it is helpful in the future .. so i just added that....

Comment: VolleySingleton  does  not work into my proyect . why ????? and i need to send a json but also get a json that the webservice send me .

Comment: @fer You need to have volleysingleton class in your app then only you can use it ...I have added volley singleton class as well as receive json response ..you can look at the updated code above .. it should work for you...