# How to post JSON in volley using android?

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working on Volley but i am quite new to this framework i have no idea how to post JSON data using volley, i have one sample JSON please tell me how to post this JSON data.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("email", "abcd@g.com");
jsonObject.put("password", "abcd123");
jsonObject.put("device", "jdghfdhgdhi");
jsonObject.put("latitude", 1.2456);
jsonObject.put("longitude", 1.3466);
```

Please kindly go through my JSON and let me know how to post this JSON using volley.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send POST request with JSON data using Volley](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23220695/send-post-request-with-json-data-using-volley Look on that answer

Comment: http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/  go through about volley.

Comment: hey thanks but in my JSON i have two double value can you tell me the code because i am completely new to Volley ???

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471006/android-volley-how-to-receive-and-send-a-json/38472251#38472251](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38471006/android-volley-how-to-receive-and-send-a-json/38472251#38472251) check here once

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, your url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(NoolReaderDashboard.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
           params .put("email", "abcd@g.com");
         params .put("password", "abcd123");
        params .put("device", "jdghfdhgdhi");
        params .put("latitude", 1.2456);
         params .put("longitude", 1.3466);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: hey thanks but in params .put("latitude", 1.2456); params .put("longitude", 1.3466); it's showing error "Wrong arguments Found double"

Comment: params .put("latitude",String.valueOf(1.2456)); and params .put("longitude", String.valueOf(1.3466));

Comment: convert to string and pass it like(1.2456+""   or  String.valueOf(1.2456));)@AnshumanPattnaik

Comment: no as per the backend API design, it wants latitude and longitude in double format not string

Comment: they will convert into double format ask it to your backend developer@AnshumanPattnaik

Answer (score 0):

private void Postdata() {

```
    String url = "http://www.example.com";                              //url where you want to post data
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("response is","==>"+response);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d("Response-------", "------>" + response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Responce error==","===>"+error);
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    ) {

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            // the POST parameters:
            params.put("email", "abcd@g.com");
            params.put("password", "abcd123");
            params.put("latitude", 1.2456);
            params.put("longitude", 1.3466);
            Log.d("Value is ----------", ">" + params);
            return params;
        }
    };
    MyApplication .getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
}
```